# Querydsl nested query generated an error sql

Tags: sql, syntax-error, querydsl

I wrote a simple nested query

```
@Autowired
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
@Autowired
Configuration configuration;
private JPASQLQuery<?> queryFactory;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    queryFactory = new JPASQLQuery<>(entityManager, configuration);
}

public void student() {

    QStudent student = new QStudent("student");
    QStudent nested = new QStudent("nested");

    List<?> fetch = queryFactory.select(student.id)
            .from(SQLExpressions.select(nested.id)
                    .from(nested), student)
            .fetch();

}
```

The entity structure is like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "u_student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

The generated sql is like this

> select student.id
>   from u_student (select nested.id
>   from u_student nested) as student

Outside sql added a tableName up, causing sql syntax error

Am I wrong? How should such a nested query be written?

The first time you send a question is not very useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found that using PathBuilder can solve this problem

The complete code is:

```
    PathBuilder<Tuple> studentAlias = new PathBuilder<>(Tuple.class,"student");
    QStudent student = new QStudent("student");
    QStudent nested = new QStudent("nested");

    List<?> fetch = queryFactory.select(student)
            .from(SQLExpressions.select(nested.id)
                    .from(nested), studentAlias)
            .fetch();
```

Generated sql:

```
select student.id as id1_90_0_
from (select nested.id from u_student nested) as student
```

Do you have any better plans?